# Protractor and jasmine: with firefox, I can´t click on button because another element obscures it

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I can´t click on  button:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
elementToClick.isEnabled().then(function(isEnabled) {
  if (isEnabled) {
    console.log('button enabled');
    browser.
    wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToClick), 50000)
      .then(function() {
        elementToClick.click();
      });
  }
});
```

Click fails due:

> Failed: Element  is not clickable at point (1781.908317565918,887) because another element  obscures it

Do you know why?

The class modal fade show d-block is on top of button div.

Comment: I once had the same problem, it happened on google chrome and browsers using the same engine only. I was forced to add a sleep.

Comment: I'm using firefox. 
I added a browser.sleep(10000) before but didn´t solve it.

Comment: This issue only happens with firefox.

Comment: try to click the element via `browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', element);`.